# how to implement a sql query that requires some one to one joins and then many to many?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could please advise me on how to implement this query that requires first linking tables that have a one-to-one relationship and then need to link in a many-to-many relationship, I share an example of the structure of the tables:

```
table1
    id
    name
    date

table2
    id
    table1_id
    country

table3
    id
    first_name
    last_name

table4
    id
    table3_id
    type
    city

table1_table3
    id
    table1_id
    table3_id

table5
    id
    somefield

table1_table5
    id
    table1_id
    table5_id
```

Now I try this query but I do not know how I should implement the many-to-many bond

```
select
  table1.id                             id,
  table3.first_name                     first_name,
  table3.last_name                      last_name,
  table4.type                           type,
  table4.city                           city,
  table2.country                        country,
  table5.somefield                      somefield
from
  table1 table1
    inner join
  table2 table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
    inner  join
  table3 table3
    inner join
  table4 table4 on table4.table3_id = table3.id
    inner join
  table5 table5
where
  table1.date > '2018-05-04'
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use normal join relationships:

```
select
  t1.id                             id,
  t3.first_name                     first_name,
  t3.last_name                      last_name,
  t4.type                           type,
  t4.city                           city,
  t2.country                        country,
  t5.somefield                      somefield
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
    join table1_table3 t13 on t13.table1_id = t1.id
    join table3 t3 on t3.id = t13.table3_id
    join table4 t4 on t4.table3_id = t3.id
    join table1_table5 t15 on t15.table1_id = t1.id
    join table5 t5 on t5.id = t15.table5_id
where
  t1.date > '2018-05-04'
```

Also:

- I improved readability by using shorter aliases such as `t1`.
- I replaced `inner join` by just `join` since `inner` is redundant. You can add then back if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this works for you, but table `table1_table5` should probably be joined with an on-clause like this

```
join table1_table5
on table1_table5.table1_id = table1.id
```

and below that table `table5` should propably be joined like this

```
join table5 table5
on table1_table5.table5_id = table5.id
```

btw: you can use `and` for multiple conditions in an on-clause